# Flutter Firestore - Show a specific document with all the values it has

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to show a document when an user goes to the profile page to see their own informations. What I have done so far is:

```
  class Profile extends StatefulWidget {

  Profile({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();

}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {

  Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  List<DocumentSnapshot> _members = [];

  bool _loading = true;

  _getMember() async {
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
   Query query = _firestore.collection("membership");
    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
    });
   QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.getDocuments();
   _members = querySnapshot.documents;
     setState(() {
     _loading = false;
   });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getMember();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Profile"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: _members.length == 0 ? Center(child: Text("empty"),) : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _members.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(_members[index].data["name"]),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But this only shows name. Also, it shows another document from same collection which I don't want to happen.

[My collection:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlCMk.png)

My question is:
 How can I get data of a specific document with all of the values in the document?
 With specific order, FOR EXAMPLE:

Name: gün

Surname: uluutku

Age: 59

Weight: 90

Phone Number: +05075326895

NOTE: I use user IDs as a document ID.

Comment: sry, but is this not rather obvious? you can just do it like you did with "name", so for surname its `_members[index].data["surname"]`, and so on. And to access a specific document use `final DocumentReference docRef = _firestore.collection("membership").document("userId");`, instead of querying the whole collection.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comment, you have to follow the path down to Document instead of just querying the whole Collection to gather the information from the user. This is an example of how to retrieve the document by using the user ID:

```
  void _onPressed() async{
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    firestoreInstance.collection("users").document(firebaseUser.uid).get().then((value){
      print(value.data);
    });
  }
```

You can find more examples on how to do it from [here](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-in-flutter-9ea80593ca40)

Comment: I asked for retrive a data from firestore not adding data to firestore.

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong piece of code, I edited the post to reflect the correct one. But all of them came from the page linked in my answer.

Comment: I have looked that link before writing here. It did not helped me. Maybe I didn't understand its logic or its not for my code, I don't know.